# How to send Translated email body using Custom Label and Messaging SingleEmailMessage

Tags: email, singleemailmessage, customlabel, translation-workbench

I created a Custom Label and added translation for Spanish. I am calling this Custom Label in the Email Subject Body. How can I implement the translated email depending upon User LanguageLocaleKey?

```
 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
 List<String> subj = new List<String>();
 List<String> body = new List<String>();
 subj.add(mark);
 body.add(mark1);
 String Subject = String.format(System.Label.NotiSubject, subj);
 String messageBody = String.format(System.Label.NotiBody, body);
 mail.setSubject(Subject);
 mail.setHtmlBody(messageBody);
 mailList.add(mail); 
 Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);
```

Comment: Did you verified the email? Custom labels do automatically translate based on `User.LanguageLocaleKey`?

Comment: I triggered an email. But it didn't get translated. There are multiple recipients to the email. Do you want me try individually?

Comment: Which user context does this class run? guest ? system?

Comment: I tried using single recipient. Still not getting translated. I am not sure what you meant by user context but to give a gist, I am querying over a custom object records and then sending them to a specific queue member based on the record. For the moment, I am calling the class from anonymous window.

Comment: Do I need to pass `User.LanguageLocaleKey` while calling custom label?

Comment: You can use Visualforce Template to achieve that. Here is a link might help you https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_messaging_emailTemplate.htm.

Comment: So when you call it from execute anonymous. Doesn't it translate based on LanguageLocaleKey from your user? No you don't need to pass anything, platform does this itself. Just make sure you have added translations for that specific language!

Comment: @SachinHooda Okay Now I got it. So the locale depends on the user who is calling the class not the recipients

Comment: Is there any way I can make it depended on the recipients locale

Comment: @SalesforceDevelopment Is there any way to avoid this? Then I need to make a lot of changes which I want to avoid.

Comment: Yes @Beta Tester it depends on the user calling this method. It believe the best way is to use a template. You can directly specify language based on user locale.

Comment: YEah got it. THanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visualforce Template to achieve that. Here is a link might help you https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_messaging_emailTemplate.htm.

Use this method to generate email content dynamically in apex class
renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, whoId, whatId)

TemplateId => Visualforce Template Id
WhoId => Recipient ( Lead/Contact/User )
WhatId => The record you want to use to display email content dynamically.